# How to handle specific exceptions in Bigquery?

Tags: python-3.x, stored-procedures, plsql, google-bigquery, oracle11g

[image: oracle and bigquery procedures]

I have used Google Cloud SQL Translation Tool.

How to convert specific errors in Bigquery procedures?

The part 'WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
some_output := 5000;' in Oracle SQL procedure has not been converted by GOOGLE SQL.

How to add these error conditions in Bigquery procedures?

If there is any workaround in Python for this, then that would also be helpful.

This code does not require 'WHEN OTHERS THEN' but I have used it just to exemplify that 'WHEN OTHERS THEN' part is converted by Bigquery but it skips when specific error is mentioned like zero_divide or any specific error, which could be required in the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know BigQuery.

Code you posted (on left hand side) doesn't make much sense to me; why does it calculate `quot` but - if something happens - you don't set its value but `n_sales_out`?

Anyway: for `zero_divide`, you can use `if-then-else`:

```
  if tv_done = 0 then
     n_sales_out := 5000;   --> this handles is WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE
  else
     quot := n_sales / tv_done;
  end if;
```

As of `when others`, well, you'll have to figure out what that might be. What other errors do you expect in that simple `quot := n_sales / tv_done` calculation? What could go wrong (apart from zero_divide)?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery does have [exception handling](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#beginexceptionend) for procedures, but in this case it looks like you want:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(SAFE_DIVIDE(1, 0), 5000)
```

`SAFE_DIVIDE` will return `NULL` if you try to divide by zero, so you can then coalesce that with a default value.